# xna game studio 4 - эффекты

Tags: xna-4, графика, разработка-игр, c#

Как можно сделать красивые 2D эффекты? Например, используя системы частиц и не только...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если на PC/Xbox то проще всего шейдерами, на WP7 придется разбираться со спрайтами и эффектами наложения.

Посмотрите например вот этот пример: [Particle Systems Using XML and the Content Pipeline](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/particle_xml) или другие семплы по шейдерам с того же сайта. Вообще на AppHub очень много материалов и статей по XNA.

А так же обратите внимание на вот этот урок: [facewound.com/tutorials/shader1/](http://www.facewound.com/tutorials/shader1/).
А еще русский ресурс по xna: [xnadev.ru](http://xnadev.ru), там тоже много статей и отзывчивый форум.